# Formatting ArrayList of Integers

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, formatting, format

I currently have this code, but when it's printed, it prints the integers on different lines one right after another. How can I format this, so that it prints like this: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]

I've tried converting the ArrayList to an array, but I must not being doing it correctly because it doesn't seem to be working.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PartBMod {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your array of integers (using commas to separate them, no spaces): ");
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String str = new String(input.nextLine());
    String[] array = str.split(",");

    for (String i : array) {
        arrayList.add(Integer.parseInt(i));

    }

    Collections.sort(arrayList);

    for (Integer i : arrayList) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `nextLine()` returns a String, so why the `new String()` around it? It's meaningless and a waste.

Comment: I just started learning Java last week, so I'm still getting the hang of things like that. Thanks for the tip, it lets me know what's unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Your desired format is the default for `ArrayList`. You could use

```
System.out.println(arrayList);
```

Comment: Didn't realize the fix was so simple. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Elliot's answer notwithstanding, if `toString()` didn't happen to be what you wanted, you could roll your own in just one statement:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.stream(input.nextLine().split(","))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .sort()
    .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.join(",", "[", "]")));
```

Comment: Or you could use `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(input.nextLine())`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this simple way:

```
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(arrayList.get(i));
        if(i != arrayList.size()-1)
            System.out.print(", ");

    }
    System.out.println("]");
```

Comment: The conditional print of the comma is better done *before* the value, as `if (i > 0)`. Shorter, simpler.

Answer (score -1):

The reason your code isn't working the way you want it to is because you are using println. It will add a new line after printing each item. What I would do is something like this

```
String textToPrint = "[ ";
for (int i =0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    textToPrint += String.valueOf(i) + ", ";
}
textToPrint = textToPrint.substring(0, textToPrint.length() -2);
textToPrint += "]";
System.out.println(textToPrint);
```

This way you are adding each integer into a string to print. 
Elliots' answer is cleaner and more efficient in this case, but this loop may be needed in other cases.
The substring line removes a trailing comma and space. IMO it's cleaner than adding an if statement into the for loop.

Comment: That will print a comma after the last value.

Comment: Will produce bad results if list is empty.

Comment: I fixed it. I used the for loop shortcut used in the question and didnt think to change it. Thanks.

Comment: Now you're listing numbers `0` to `size-1`, and not the elements of the array. You're getting further away from the goal. Suggest you just delete this incorrect answer, since @Shahid already has an [answer similar to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39313698/5221149) that actually works.